# Firebase ML Vision package is DISCONTINUED for flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, ocr, google-mlkit, vision-api

This is my first question in Stackoverflow. As of June 18, 2021 [firebase_ml_vision](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ml_vision) is working only on device and cannot connect to cloud vision API, I was not able to OCR **Chinese** texts.

I tried this package [google_ml_kit](https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit). It works but it also cannot connect to cloud vision api.

I want to OCR **Chinese** text. How can I do that with ML kit? Because on device text recognition can only detect Latin alphabets.

I found this https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/vision-annotate-images. How to use this in flutter app? Or is there any other way?

UPDATE:
the package is updated and it can detect Chinese text.

Answer (score 0):

The updated approach to access the cloud-based text recognition ML APIs is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/android/recognize-text). It relies on having the app talk to a Cloud Function, which then calls the Cloud AI API (send image and get results). The documentation includes the steps for Android and iOS, but accessing the Functions endpoint from Flutter will be similar.